# Adjoint Functors: Naturality?

Tags: category-theory, definition

Given a pair of functors:
$$F:\mathcal{B}\to\mathcal{A}\quad G:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$$
Consider an identification:
$$\alpha:F(B)\to A\leftrightarrow\beta:B\to G(A)$$
Then they're adjoints if the identification is natural.

What does natural mean in this context?

Comment: As with many notions in category theory, naturalness can be expressed by commuting diagrams.

Comment: @hardmath: Yep I tried to figure out what it could mean here. Can you help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most textbooks it means a natural transformation between two functors from $\mathcal{B}^{op}\times\mathcal{A}$ to sets, namely $Hom(F(\_),\_)$ and  $Hom(\_,G(\_))$.  The notation is not quite right but I hope it is clearer this way than if I wrote in the projection functors.

Really, though, you should also see Lawvere's version at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category where it is not a natural transformation but an isomorphism of comma categories.

The proof that the two agree (modulo details of foundations) is worth working through just to understand what adjunction really is.

Comment: By "between two functors from [...] to sets" you don't mean the original ones but these obscure functors with blank spaces, do you?

Comment: No.  The original functors were from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{A}$ and back.  I refer to two functors from $\mathcal{B}^{op}\times\mathcal{A}$ to sets.

Comment: Obscure?  I fear you have to know what Hom functors are to use that definition of adjoints.  Maybe you will find comma categories less obscure.

Comment: Wow I'm amazed: *"This chapter represents the high point of this book, the goal toward which we have been working steadily. The notion of adjoint functor, first discovered by D. Kan in the 1950s, applies everything that we have learned up to now to unify and subsume all of the different universal mapping properties that we have encountered, from free groups to limits to exponentials."*